# Adding time values that equal more than 24 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to sum up some time values, and when my sum exceeds 24 hours it subtracts 24 from the total.

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT 
    UserID,
    First_NM,
    Last_NM,
    MgrName,
    CONVERT(varchar(5),  DATEADD(minute, SUM(OnProd)/60, 0), 114) as OnProd,
    CONVERT(varchar(5),  DATEADD(minute, SUM(OffProd)/60, 0), 114) as OffProd, 
    CONVERT(varchar(5),  DATEADD(minute, SUM(OnProd+OffProd)/60, 0), 114) as SumProd    

FROM (
    SELECT 
        UserID,
        First_NM,
        Last_NM,
        MgrName,
        CASE WHEN WorkUnitType LIKE '%On%' THEN DATEDIFF(s, DateStart, DateEnd) ELSE 0 END AS OnProd,
        CASE WHEN WorkUnitType LIKE '%Off%' THEN DATEDIFF(s, DateStart, DateEnd) ELSE 0 END AS OffProd

    FROM dbo.vw_mos_DPL_Reporting

    ) a 
Group By 
    UserID,
    First_NM,
    Last_NM,
    MgrName
```

And here's my current output:

```
UserID         First_NM     Last_NM     OnProd  OffProd SumProd
A05878         STEVEN       LANTE       22:28   09:55   08:23
ARGLIN         ARNIE        FREEL       00:00   00:00   00:00
B96695         JENNIFER     LARK        21:32   18:49   16:21
PATYOI         PATTY        TROTTER     04:29   00:03   04:32
```

How would I go about fixing this?  Just to be clear, I want to show something like 38:24 or whatever the actual sum is.  Total hours:Total minutes/60

Comment: Of the 4 people, who got their `SumProd` wrong?

Comment: You are selecting from what looks like datetime but using datediff to convert to seconds (duration), so that you can use dateadd to add it to 0 to convert it back into a date?  It would seem to me you are calculating the difference in duration and not the difference of the datetimes.  What is the actual requirement?

Comment: DATEADD(minute, SUM(OnProd+OffProd)/60, 0) is going to return DAYS, Hours and minutes, just showing the hours and minutes with 114 is just truncating off the days portion.

Comment: For the first user, Steven, the SumProd field should equal 32:23 (the sum of 22:28 and 9:55 in a time-based environment).  The 3rd user, Jennifer, should have a SumProd of 40:21 using the same logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little inelegant, but you might try calculating the minutes and the hours separately and concatenating, eg, instead of

```
CONVERT(varchar(5),  DATEADD(minute, SUM(OnProd)/60, 0), 114) as OnProd
```

try

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(OnProd)/3600 AS VARCHAR(6)) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CAST((SUM(OnProd) % 3600) / 60 AS VARCHAR(6)),2) AS OnProd
```

You have to do the same thing for OffProd and SumProd as well.